# Show data after receiving from database PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, bootstrap-4

This is my PHP code, which will display data when I click the button. I want to display the data for the specified card when I click the button for the number 1. I want to display all information in card 1, but my code will display all information. Can anyone help me?
http://www.m9c.net/uploads/15678158911.png

```
<? $title= 'Show CV'; 
   $quariy = ("select * from information where selector ='2'");
   $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $quariy) or die("database 
   error:". mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
   while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {?>

 <form action="" method = "post" class= "pl-4 pr-4">
     <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Your Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" 
value="<?php echo $data['name'] ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="education">Your Education</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" 
 name="education" value="<?php echo $data['education']?>" >
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact_information"> Contact 
Information </label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" 
 name="contact_information" rows="3"><?php echo 
 $data['contact_information'] ?></textarea></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="skills">Skills</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="skills" 
rows="3"><?php echo $data['skills'] ?></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="work">Work Experiences </label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="work" 
 rows="3"> 
<?php echo $data['work'] ?></textarea></div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="projects">Projects </label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="projects" 
                    rows="3"><?php echo $data['projects'] ?> 
                    </textarea>
                    </div></div><?php }?></form>
```

Comment: What is the schema for your `information` table? Do you have some sort of an `id` field to select the specific card? If so - you should add it to your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318368/mysqli-or-die-does-it-have-to-die